# How to get visible map bounds in mapbox js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm working website which uses a lot of markers. And for performance reasons I'm going to render only visible markers after each move.
I'm using mapbox js library via [react-mapbox-gl](http://alex3165.github.io/react-mapbox-gl/) react library.
Any advice how to get visible coordinates from map? Top left and bottom right visible coordinates is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map.getBounds()` or `map.getBounds().toArray()`.